# Replace all the URL references to a file when it's replaced with another file in Firebase - Flutter mobile apps

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, mobile-application

I am building a mobile app using Flutter and have several collections in my Firebase Database, such as `userData`, `posts`, `chats`, etc.

I refer to user's profile picture URL (which is stored in Firebase Storage) in the `posts` collection as well. If a user changes their profile picture, the URL is only directly updated in the `userData` collection. Is there an easy way to update the URL in the `posts` collection (and all the other collections that the URL is referred to) without let's say looping through all the posts and updating the URL wherever it's found?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> without let's say looping through all the posts and updating the URL wherever it's found?

No, that's precisely what you're going to have to do, except you don't have to read all the documents.  Just query for the ones that match what you need to change.  Firestore doesn't have a "update where" type of query that can update multiple documents in a single operation.

Comment: Hi Doug, Thanks for the response. Both your response and Eduardo's (below) work. I was wondering if you could take a look at his response below and let me know if your approach can provide any additional benefits or you think both are equally good? I am mainly looking for an approach that is faster and results in fewer number of requests to the server to minimize server costs. Thanks!

Comment: It's a matter of preference.  There are clear tradeoffs here, and you'll have to decide if you want more difficult update or more difficult queries.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is saving the photo url only in the users collection like you do, then in the others collections you save the uid of the user instead of his photo url, finally, in the client side, you query the user data based on the uid, in this way you only need to save and update the photo url in one collection

Comment: Hi Eduardo. Thanks for the response. How would I query the user data in the client side? Should I use a streambuilder? I am displaying multiple users in a single screen. Sorry if it's a stupid question, but I am pretty new to this whole thing and just trying to learn.

Comment: Yes, you can use a StreamBuilder, and then inside your ListView.Builder you send the user UID to each item, and finally inside your item you query the user information